# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined issue when doing unit test in angular5

Tags: angular5, karma-jasmine

I am trying to do unit test in angular5 and also solving most of the testing errors showing while typing the command 'ng test'.But I stuck with  following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

I am using javascript string split() method in my component for spliting a string.

```
this.currentUrlPath = this.router.url;
this.currentUrlPathAsArray = this.currentUrlPath.split('/');
this.currentUrlPathAsArray.shift();  
this.currentOfferKey = this.currentUrlPathAsArray[0].split('offer-')[1].split('-program')[0];
```

But I can't understand what the above error means?

Comment: What is the value of `this.currentUrlPathAsArray` that you are passing. It is throwing this error due to the wrong data.

Comment: @SujataChanda i am retrieving current router url and split it based on '/' seperator and stores these results in 'currentUrlPathAsArray' variable.I am edited the question, please review it.

Comment: Ok so what is the url then?

Comment: this is the url 'http://localhost:4200/offer-yachting-playgrounds-program'

Comment: If you need `yachting-playgrounds` then `this.currentUrlPath .split('offer-')[1].split('-program')[0];` will do. `this.currentUrlPathAsArray[0]` is returning `""` and `this.currentUrlPathAsArray[2] is giving `"offer-yachting-playgrounds-program"` . So `this.currentUrlPathAsArray[2].split('offer-')[1].split('-program')[0];` will also work.